# Add gap between group items in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I add a gap (lets say 20dp) between group items in `ExpandableListView`? I have custom group layout with `RelativeLayout` as a parent. Adding margins to parent doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you're aiming for but here's an idea

Pass the list you got in your main activity to your custom list

```
MyExpandableListAdapter myAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(expandableList);
```

in your custom list class methods:

```
private ExpandableListView exp;

public MyExpandableListAdapter(ExpandableListView exp)
{
    this.exp = exp;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
    }

    exp.setDividerHeight(0);

    return convertView;

}


public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    exp.setDividerHeight(20);

    return convertView;
}
```

for example, this should add spacing between groups and not the childs

Comment: Seems like I should have been reading `ExpandableListView` specs more careful - second my question and second one-line solution. Thanks, just what I need.

Comment: I dont think that would've helped you much, I've just been using expandableList too much, and you're very welcome

Comment: @Stupidus this works for me , but in this case the increased area has gray in color and my list background is in white in color which seems awkward :(.... can you suggest solution for this

Comment: @YS Bhai Is it on the child divider or group divider thats gray? or what is gray?

Comment: This is not working. It gives random divider heights.

Answer (score 0):

For the future, In the xml layout, you can just add `android:dividerHeight"` to your `ExpandableListView` and also you can adjust divider color:

```
       <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/red"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:indicatorLeft="? 
        android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
        />
```