# How to remove specific space between parent and child in an ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Can you help me identify why there is a space between the group and the child? In my case I want spaces between all groups and the child should be right below the group with no space (but of course space to the next group. My problem looks like this:
[image]

I have set the Group divider to this drawable (expandable_list_group_divider):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

And the child divider to this (@drawable/expandable_list_child_divider):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

I have defined the layout like this in the xml(it is a compund control):

```
<com.jws.MyExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@drawable/expandable_list_group_divider"
        android:childDivider="@drawable/expandable_list_child_divider"/>
```

The custom view class:

```
public class MyExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {
    protected ArrayList<Departure> departures;

    public MyExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setGroupIndicator(null);
        setChildIndicator(null);
        setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        setFadingEdgeLength(60);

        departures = new ArrayList<Departure>();
        this.setAdapter(new MyExpandableListAdapter(context, this, departures));
    }
}
```

And finally the expandable list adapter

```
public class DeparturesExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private final int DIVIDER_HEIGHT = 20;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Departure> departures;
    private Context context;
    private ExpandableListView expListView;

    public DeparturesExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ExpandableListView expListView, ArrayList<Departure> departures)
    {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.departures = departures;
        this.expListView = expListView;
    }


    // This Function used to inflate parent rows view
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
    {
        final Departure departure = departures.get(groupPosition);

        if(!isExpanded)
            expListView.setDividerHeight(DIVIDER_HEIGHT);
        else
            expListView.setDividerHeight(-4);

        expListView.setFooterDividersEnabled(false);

        // Inflate grouprow.xml file for parent rows
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_departure_overview, parentView, false);

        //Data handling in the view...

        return convertView;
    }


    // This Function used to inflate child rows view
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
    {
        final Departure departure = departures.get(groupPosition);

        if(isLastChild)
            expListView.setDividerHeight(DIVIDER_HEIGHT);

        // Inflate childrow.xml file for child rows
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_departure_details, parentView, false);

        //Data handling...

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return departures.get(groupPosition);
    }

    //Call when child row clicked
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return 1;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return departures.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        if(departures != null)
            return departures.size();

        return 0;
    }

    //Call when parent row clicked
    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged()
    {
        // Refresh List rows
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return ((departures == null) || departures.isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Image for comments:
[image]

Comment: post MyExpandableListView class, and also what happen if yu add another child to the parent?? does it have a margin to the next child?

Comment: Try this [SO solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13679388/2083078), it worked for me.

Comment: Tha solution somehow Works. However, when scrolling in the list the spaces and non spaces gets moved around so the groups gets no Space and the child gets the Space. I don't know if this can be an index problem?

Comment: I have added some more code snippets now. Hope it helps.

Comment: have you tried setting negative top margin/padding on your child's layout?

Comment: I can give it negative values and it works, but I cannot have the layout be be as needed then.

Comment: Can share layout for listitem, both group and child.

Comment: @FireFly3000 - Perhaps you could try a height of "1dp" for the child divider and see if it makes any difference. I think that "0dp" might be causing problems.

Answer (score 6):

this is tested and is proven to work, i wanted to come back to this even months later because none of the other methods gave me results quite how i wanted them. these are displayed exactly how OP (and myself) wanted

this is my groups or categories or whatever. basically the first linear layout is just a wrapper for a view which acts as a spacer between the categories, and then another linear layout that handles all my formatting

in the ExpandableListView(not shown) i have the divider height set to 0. the spacing is instead handled by the views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#50601CBA">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

then in the child i have this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#50601CBA"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the following settings in the xml file and there is no gap between the parent and the child.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_black"
                android:divider="#FF8800"
                android:dividerHeight="2px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Most probably this is an issue with a margin setting you've got.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it doesn't Work like that in my case. I don't see any changes :(

Comment: can you paste the code of your class and of your adapter please?

Comment: what if you remove `DIVIDER_HEIGHT` in the DeparturesExpandableListAdapter? Line 2.

Comment: That also Means that I will remove all the setDividerHeight code in the adapter. If I do so it looks like the second image I have posted. The oranges are the Group dividers and the Blacks the child dividers.

Comment: Then just decrease its size.

Comment: could you check if the view_departure_details.xml file has any margins? I would remove those

Comment: Hi @FireFly3000 can you please accept the answer if this has helped you?

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove dividers just from the child views and not between the parents in the expandable List:

add android:childDivider="#00000000" in the ExapandableListView attributes in XML:

```
<ExpandableListView
android:id="@+id/elv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:childDivider="#00000000" 
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
/>
```

Refer http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/working-with-the-expandablelistview-part-1/

Comment: Changing the color to 'transparent' doesn't remove the excess space. It just matches the space's color to that of the background.

Comment: and also remove margin Top and margin bottom from parent and child layout ( in xml file )

Comment: it doesn't change anything, the space is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the margins and divider height, and instead add a blank space on top of groupview itself. It should do the trick.

Comment: For e.g. wrap the container of view_departure_overview.xml with another view, and supply your old container with margin.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want spacing between the parents, but not between parent & child. 
I have failed to find a proper way of achieving it. So I did a not a smart fix, by not setting the divider height, instead since I had a custom layout for every parent item, I added a LinearLayout with a fixed height of 25dp at the top of my custom parent layout, as a result I could achieve the desire functionality, but there was a side effect , when you touch the list item, the spacing as well as the list item both are highlighted on touch.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative margin for child view in view_departure_details.Something like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="text1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
android:text="@string/my_best_text"
android:background="#FF0000"
/>
```

I know some people consider it a bad practice to use negative margin but right it seems to be the easiest way.

Other way(the time-consuming way) is to implement you own expandable listview so that you have more control on how things are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Set the child view programmatically like:

expandableListView.setDividerHeight(1);

expandableListView.setChildDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.Black);

And group view From xml like :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
         />


<View
    android:id="@+id/header_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Transparency between them like..

```
        android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the view's padding in the method `public View getChildView()` using the [setPadding()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method of the view.

Example:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parentView){
 final Departure departure = departures.get(groupPosition);

 if(isLastChild)
  expListView.setDividerHeight(DIVIDER_HEIGHT);

 // Inflate childrow.xml file for child rows
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_departure_details, parentView, false);

 //Data handling...

 convertView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

 return convertView;
}
```

In the same way, if you want modify padding of the group, you will have to modify the padding in the `getGroupView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just set the child background color as same of exandableListView

example:


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:indicatorLeft="@null"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:background="@color/colorGrayTransparent"
         />
and child item color like this :

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGrayTransparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
....
</LinearLayout>
```